# Cannot open layer and Cannot open data source in readOGR

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, rgdal

I have the rgdal abd raster libraries running

I'm trying to open a .shp map in R
I've already tried

```
setwd("C:/Users/user/Documents/tarso first paper/R")
study_area <- readOGR("municipios.shp")
```

did not work
so I tried

```
study_area <- readOGR("C:/Users/user/Documents/tarso first paper/R/municipios.shp")
study_area <- readOGR("C:/Users/user/Documents/tarso first paper/R","municipios.shp")
study_area <- readOGR("C:/Users/user/Documents/tarso first paper/R/municipios")
study_area <- readOGR("C:/Users/user/Documents/tarso first paper/R","municipios")
```

Also, it didn't work...
Whenever there is one of the 2 types of error message, "Cannot open layer" or "Cannot open data"

Data source is governmental and open in Qgiz
So the data is probably ok

I have no idea how to fix it....

Comment: Are you opening that Shapefile with QGIS from that exact location? Are .shx and .dbf files there as well? What's the output from `list.files("C:/Users/user/Documents/tarso first paper/R/", pattern = "municipios")` ? Are `sf::st_read()` or `terra::vect()`  able to load it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `readOGR` anymore because the underlying package (rgdal) will be retired soon. Instead of "raster" you should now use "terra".

For example:

```
f <- "municipios.shp"
## check if all files needed exist
ff <- c(f, sapply(c(".shx", ".dbf"), \(ext) gsub("\\.shp$", ext, f)))
all(file.exists(ff))
# TRUE

## open with terra
library(terra)
v <- vect(f)
```